# Create Test Case in version 14

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am playing with Enterprise Architect for the first time and looking at options for adding Test Cases.  I have found a way to add A test case element -

[Right-click on element | Properties | Responsibilities > Scenarios > Structured Specification](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/modeling_tools/generate_test_cases.html)

and this seems to get me where I want quicker as we aren't using Use Case diagrams right now.

While I'm looking at options though  I wanted to check, a lot of documentation says, and a Youtube entry shows that you can add a test case from the tool box in a Use Case Diagram.  I don't have that option though, in Use Case I just have Actor, Use Case and Boundary.  Is this a version thing and it's been deprecated or am I missing a trick ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a test case element from the **custom** and **maintenance** toolboxes

[image]

Since v14 Sparx has somewhat cleaned up the toolboxes and removed the Test Case (which is not defined in UML) from the UML Use Case toolbox.

Comment: Thanks I guess I should have seen that.  I'm just looking at it for the first time and guess I need to make sure any docs I take real note of are for v14.